# How to modify tect of AST node in java?

Tags: java, antlr

how to modify an AST node and add a new node? I am using Java for this. Please help.

Comment: What kind of AST? What do you have so far?

Comment: I am actually parsing oracle constructs and I need to modify AST node e.g. if I have a table name abc in an AST node then I want to replace this with xyz.

Comment: You have build an own SQL parser? Or do you use the existing SQL grammar available for antlr?

Comment: I have built my own oracle sql parser.

Comment: As far as I remember, default node classes are immutable. You have to specify a custom AST class to get the setters.

Comment: May a suggest you try an already existent parser like https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser.

Comment: The "best" approach is not to modify an AST node but add some additional information in it. Simply sub-class ANTLR's node class (Or Lexer node class). Add some attributes into it. Specify your class as `TokenClass` in ANTLR grammar. Then store some additional information this token using rule actions. PS: I'm about to think we both work on the same type of software.

Comment: Just for curiosity @ivan and user: why not use something existing? What kind of special possibilities are you up to that other implementations lack?

Comment: @wumpz look at these examples: https://github.com/ibre5041/plsql-parser/tree/master/tests "mine" parser implements most of Oracle's extensions.

Comment: @ivan May I reuse these test sqls for checking against JSqlParser? I am quite curious to see the result.

Comment: @wumpz sure. It's public domain. BSD license if remember well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48898/discussion-between-ivan-and-wumpz)

Comment: The JSQLParser won't help in my case as we need to transform the Oracle SQL into MySQL, SQLServer, and Teradata SQL.

Comment: So why is JSqlParser not useable here? It can parse all kinds of database syntax and is not forced to e.g. Oracle. So you can build constructs for serveral databases. Imho it is easier because you do not have to handle a complete AST but a already SQL related object hierarchy. Could you give an example so I would give you one back, if I am able to handle it?